# How can I retrieve data from Meteor collection on the client side with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to retrieve my server data of a collection with the code bellow, but it just return undefined.

```js
import { Posts } from '../../../api/posts.js';

class FeedUnit extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          open: true,
          emojis: false,
          isOver: false,
          likes: this.setLike(),
      };
  }
  
    setLike(){
    let self = this;
    let like;

    let post = Posts.findOne({ external_id: this.props.data.id });
    console.log(Posts.findOne({}))
    return like;
  }
```

I already search on the data base manually and there I had the correct return using the command:

```js
db.posts.findOne({external_id: '1402366059774445_1503319816345735'})
```

Comment: let post = Posts.findOne({ external_id: self.props.data.id });

Comment: the collection Posts will contain no documents unless you `publish` a cursor to Post from the server and `subscribe` to it in the client.

Comment: Thank you @mostafizrahman, it was the solution!

Comment: hahaha!!!
apparently I  missed 25 points at least!

Comment: Well, you give me a tip, it wasn't exactly the answer, but it helped a lot hahaha, I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the comment of @mostafiz rahman, I should put the `publish` and `subscribe`, like this:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  // This is necessary to reatrieve data on the client side
  Meteor.publish('posts', function tasksPublication() {
    return Posts.find();
  });
}
```

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is a best solution that use some connector for Meteor/react. I prefer [react-komposer](https://github.com/arunoda/react-komposer).

U must just create function that allow react to track changes in Meteor collection:

```
function getTrackerLoader(reactiveMapper) {
  return (props, onData, env) => {
    let trackerCleanup = null;
    const handler = Tracker.nonreactive(() => {
      return Tracker.autorun(() => {
        // assign the custom clean-up function.
        trackerCleanup = reactiveMapper(props, onData, env);
      });
    });

    return () => {
      if(typeof trackerCleanup === 'function') trackerCleanup();
      return handler.stop();
    };
  };
}
```

And after that wrap component:

```
    import { Posts } from '../../../api/posts.js';

        class FeedUnit extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
              super(props);

              this.state = {
                  open: true,
                  emojis: false,
                  isOver: false,
                  likes: this.setLike(),
              };
          }

            setLike(){
              let self = this;
              let like;

              let post = this.props.post
              console.log(post)
              return like;
          }
}
function reactiveMapper(props, onData) {
    if (Meteor.subscribe('posts').ready()) {
        let post = Posts.findOne({ external_id: props.data.id });
        onData(null, { post });
    }
}

export default compose(getTrackerLoader(reactiveMapper))(FeedUnit);
```

For more information look the [docs](https://github.com/arunoda/react-komposer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Posts.findOne is async function you need either to get data from callback or by promise as below 
 Posts.findOne({ external_id: this.props.data.id })
.then((posts)=>{
//do whatever you want
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```